# Does Alexa ever stop sending the user's access token?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Alexa will automatically route requests with a populated access token based on a successful authentication, like so:

```
"user": {
  "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.LongDemoUserIdString",
  "accessToken": "asdfajweoijfoawejfajsdlkf"
}
```

My question basically the title: will Alexa ever stop sending this token along? I'm particularly curious about timeouts - if Alexa was smart enough to automatically manage putting it on my requests, will the `expires_in` also be  respected?

Answer (score 0):

If you utilize Authorization code grant as an authhentication scheme for Alexa's account linking:

> In this grant type, the authorization server provides an authorization code (code) after the user authenticates with the service. Alexa **then uses this code to request an access token / refresh token pair from the authorization server. Alexa can then use the refresh token to request a new access token after the old access token expires**.

There are situations in which Alexa will not be able to get a new access token, as the *refresh token is optional* in the first response it gets, Alexa might not be able to get a new access token after the first one expires.
In some cases even the refresh token will expire, if too many are created the first ones will usually be invalidated and it has an expiration time, usually much longer than the access token.

Also, altough you can specify a *default access token expiration time* in your alexa developer console,

> This value is used if the OAuth client does not return expires_in. If the OAuth client returns expires_in, the value provided by the OAuth client is used instead.

[Source](https://developer.amazon.com/it/docs/account-linking/configure-authorization-code-grant.html)